Can SAGE help me simplify wedge products of wedge products?
In particular, I have a vector space $V$ with basis $\{e_1, ..., e_n \}$ and I want to "foil" elements of $\bigwedge^k \bigwedge^m V$. For example, given a vector $((e_1 + e_2) \wedge e_3) \wedge (e_4 \wedge e_5)$, I want SAGE to tell me that this is $(e_1 \wedge e_3) \wedge (e_4 \wedge e_5) + (e_2 \wedge e_3) \wedge (e_4 \wedge e_5)$.
Is this something SAGE is capable of, and if so how can I get started?
Edit to add: the part I'm struggling with specifically is telling Sage I'm working with exterior powers of exterior powers.

You can get "started" by using this

The more general construction of exterior algebra is that a given vector space is extended or mapped to its corresponding exterior algebra. Sage's implementation does not seem to directly support such a construction. To be sure, I'd ask this question at Ask SageMath, or even email the authors of the ExteriorAlgebra or CliffordAlgebra modules.

You can use ExteriorAlgebra, in which the product * is the wedge:
sage: E.<e1, e2, e3, e4, e5> = ExteriorAlgebra(QQ)
sage: ((e1 + e2)*e3)*(e4*e5)
e1*e3*e4*e5 + e2*e3*e4*e5

The first line defines E to be the exterior algebra with generators e1, ..., e5. (I chose to use rational coefficients QQ, but you can use RR or CC or GF(p) or another field, or indeed any commutative ring.) The second line asks for a computation of the expression you asked about, and the third line gives Sage's answer.

There also seems to be support for Clifford algebras, although I have never used Sage's implementation.

What if I want to work in $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^2 V$? Here, $(e_1 \wedge e_2) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_3)$ is nonzero, but the current setup would evaluate this as 0.

I don't see an immediate way to do that. I see that you've now asked on  ask.sagemath.org, too.
